# C++/CLI I can't add a class to my collection

Tags: c++-cli

I am attempting to simply add a FilterInfo class to my FilterInfo collection.  I'm having a terrible time trying to understand why the following code keeps throwing the error:

> System::Collections::Generic::List::Add'
>   : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'Ziz::FilterInfo *' to
>   'Ziz::FilterInfo'

I'm only learning C++/CLI, as I'm a C# developer, and I'm sure it's something simple, but I sure could use some pointers.  My stripped code is as follows:

```
     public value class FilterInfo
    {
        public:
            char* Address;
    };

    public ref class Ziz
    {
    private:
        List<FilterInfo>^ _blockList;

    public:
        // Constructor
        Ziz(){
            _blockList = gcnew List<FilterInfo>();
        }

        List<FilterInfo>^ GetBlockList()
        {

            for each(_IPFILTERINFO ip in _packetFilter->GetBlockList())
            {
                // _IPFILTERINFO is the native C++ struct.
                FilterInfo* f = new FilterInfo();
                _blockList->Add(f);
            }
            return _blockList;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared _blockList as

```
List<FilterInfo>^ _blockList;
```

but you are trying to add

```
FilterInfo* f
```

to it. It cannot work since one is a pointer and the other one is a reference.

I'm not sure how "value" fits in but in

```
public value class FilterInfo
{
    public:
        char* Address;
};
```

You are derefore declaring an unmanaged class
to make it managed, you should use

```
public ref class FiterInfo
```

This will allow you to use FilterInfo* without having to manage memory explicitely.

Finally, char* is not so great in C++/CLI, I would recommend using System::String

Answer (score 1):

```
_blockList->Add(*f);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct your `FilterInfo` with `gcnew` as well. You can't really mix and mash these together without marshaling.

Answer (score 0):

`FilterInfo` is not `FilterInfo*`. If you want a List of pointers to FilterInfo, you need to say that `List<FilterInfo*>`. Since FilterInfo is a value class here though you'll likely just want to skip the `new`.

```
     FilterInfo fi;
     _blockList->Add(fi);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ref class A
```

{
    };

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)  
{  
      Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");  
      ICollection<A^>^ oCollection = gcnew List<A^>();  
      oCollection->Add(gcnew A());  
      return 0;  
}
```